# Como criar uma página com várias imagens? Uma sobre a outra

Tags: html, css

Estou desenhando um *layout* e já estou pensando em como será o HTML e CSS. Até consigo imaginar como fazer, porém é possível que vocês tenham opiniões e sugestões melhores.

Layout ainda em desenvolvimento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A página possui imagens separadas (Palavra "Donkey Kong", o circulo com "DK", a imagem dos macacos) e gostaria de saber quais são as maneiras de se construir isso usando HTML e CSS. É **importante** essa questão de deixar as imagens separadas pois caso eu queria adicionar algum efeito de fade com JQuery ficaria mais fácil.

Comment: Qual a melhor forma de elencar imagens uma por cima da outra! Isso tanto no HTML quando no CSS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Usando `position`:

Você pode definir as imagens com posição absoluta. Dessa forma, o posicionamento de cada uma será definido com as propriedades `top`, `bottom`, `left` e/ou `right`. Nesse caso, é melhor você ter um elemento que envolva suas imagens, para definir a posição em relação ao elemento e não (diretamente) ao `body`.
Links úteis:
<kbd>[Position: Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</kbd>
<kbd>[CSS3 - Positioning schemes: W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#positioning-schemes)</kbd>
**Código de Exemplo:**

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #ccc; /* só para exibir o bloco onde as imagens estão */
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px
}

.dixie, .diddy {
    position: absolute
}

.dixie {
    top: 15px;
    right: 150px;
    max-width: 115px
}

.diddy {
    left: 150px;
    max-width: 130px
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img class='dixie' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/A06Ly.png' alt=''/>
    <img class='diddy' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4KS.png' alt=''/>
</div>
```

---

#### Usando `transform`:

Eu acredito que a primeira alternativa seja mais fácil, no entanto existe outra maneira que é utilizar a propriedade `translate` (`translateY` e `translateX`). Você pode fazer como no exemplo anterior, utilizar `position:absolute` centralizar ambas as imagens, uma sobrepondo a outra e usar `transform` para alterar a posição da imagem verticalmente/horizontalmente em relação ao seu ponto superior esquerdo.

Links úteis (ambos tratam de `transform` no geral, não só `translate`):
 - [Transform: Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
 - [Transform: W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120403/)

<sup>Espero que a imagem deixe mais claro...</sup>
<sup>Uma imagem (`#vermelha`) e outra imagem (`#azul`).</sup>
[image: imagem-translate]

E enfim o **código de exemplo**:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px
}

.dixie, .diddy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 180px
}

.dixie {
    transform: translateX(40px);
    max-width: 120px
}

.diddy {
    transform: translateX(-40px);
    max-width: 130px
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img class='dixie' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/A06Ly.png' alt=''/>
    <img class='diddy' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4KS.png' alt=''/>
</div>
```